# php multiple insert with loop

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to insert input field data into MySQL. But the thing is that input field is vary.

take a look at my page http://www.chatfitness.com/add_malayalam.php

[image]

Jquery add input field code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1 ;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1; 
    $('#add').click(function() { 
        wordscount++;
//      $('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv); 
        $('<div id="em_in" class="line" style="display:none"><div class="word_label">English </div><input type="text" name="malayalam[]" class="input' + wordscount + ' hinput" /><a class="remScnt">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv).slideDown();
        i++; 
        return false;
    });
```

form details

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="add_word"><div class="word_label">Malayalam</div><input type="text" name="english" class="hinput" /></div>
<div id="add_words">
    <div class="line"><div class="word_label">English</div><input name="malayalam[]" class="search_word input1 hinput" type="text" /></div>

</div>
    <div id="add_wordD">+ <a id="add">Add another word</a>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit"  style="margin-left:30px;"/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

could you please give a solution for it please.
thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: I don't understand your question!

Comment: So we are suppose to know the code from html! Great! Sorry, no book taught me that.

Comment: @Michael markus-tharkun itachi I have just changed the question format. sorry my language and also i am happy for your interest :)

Comment: I still don't understand. What's happening and what's you expect? This is the same code of your page link?

Comment: what are you expecting ? where is your code simple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert each translation to separate row, this is the way:

```
<?php

$eng = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['english']);
foreach ($_POST['malayalam'] as $val) {
    $mal[] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table (english, mal) VALUES (%s, %s)",
        $eng,
        mysql_real_escape_string($mal);
    // execute query
}
```

Of course I don't know what database wrapper you use or what's the table layout.